Are there any problems with installing XPS insulation over framed walls with batts to the interior?
Location: Western New York
Project: Insulating Attached Garage
Details:

2x4 walls with no insulation
garage attached to house via one wall
double garage doors
living space above garage

I am looking to insulate the garage but want more than ~R14 in the walls (3.5" Rockwool = R14).  I could build out the walls to 2x6 but would prefer not to.
I am thinking of doing 3.5" mineral wool, then an inch or two of an XPS foam board on the inside of the garage.  My rationale for the XPS board is is that it would give me a full insulation envelope and mitigate thermal bridging from the studs.  XPS also functions as a vapour barrier so it eliminates that cost.  The XPS would then be drywalled over.
Question: Is placing XPS board on top of batt insulation an approved and recognized building practice?

I believe XPS is considered a vapor retardant, and not a vapor barrier.  In any case, you should be fine with the Rockwool & the XPS.

Overlaying rigid foam is a common strategy in my northern region, both for retrofits and new construction. It's most commonly added outside the framing, but there's no reason you can't use it inside as long as you have a reasonable moisture management strategy.

Caveat: For safety, I believe a fire blocking surface is required between the foam and living space. If you are going to put a layer of standard plasterboard over the inside surface of the foam, that should suffice. I have been told that quarter inch plywood is also acceptable; I am not sure about anything thinner.
